# How to hide caps lock icon in TextInput in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I use React Native TextInput and when I click twice capslock - icon appears. Is there a way to hide this behavior?

```
 <TextInput
    autoCompleteType="password"
    onFocus={handleOnFocus}
    textContentType="oneTimeCode"
    secureTextEntry
    placeholder="Make a strong password"
  />
```

[image]